# Jaspersoftstudio Table of contents

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create a report book for in order to have a table of contents at the beginning in jaspersoft studio version 6.2.2. I have a text field which I  have set its hyperlink parameters as declared in [Configuring the Table of Contents](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v621/configuring-table-contents). The problem is after compiling the table of contents is shown as dots and when I hover my mouse over it, i can see the real text which supposed to be there as tool tip, although I have not set the tooltip value, and there are no page numbers either! This is the code for the text field:

```
<band height="50">
        <textField hyperlinkType="" hyperlinkTarget="" bookmarkLevel="1">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="70" y="10" width="283" height="20" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="f6d9376f-7106-4292-b491-7229b297ce04"/>
            <textElement markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}+": "+$F{nameAlleinstehend}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}+":"+$F{nameAlleinstehend}]]></anchorNameExpression>
            <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA[]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
```

Anchor name expression is: `$F{id}+":"+$F{nameAlleinstehend}`
and bookmark level is set to 1. The create bookmark option is also checked for the report. Any Idea why the report looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed the font size in table of content from 16 to 8 and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Iman, you're right.

> I changed the font size in table of content from 16 to 8 and it worked!

The text fields created by default are not large enough to display text with a size of 16.

So we can either change font size or augment size of field until expression is displayed in editor.